# Is there a way to dynamically import a component's class without knowing their class name at compile time in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to do something like this:

```
import {'dynamicClassName'} from '../../../app/main-app/main-app.component';
```

and the `main-app.component` will contain:

```
export class "dynamicClassName" {}
```

I am not looking to inject components dynamically, just want to import the class whose name is going to be dynamic.

Comment: nope, I am not looking to inject components dynamically

Comment: try this `import * from '../../../app/main-app/main-app.component';`

Comment: how do I use it to invoke functions of that class?

Comment: than you can use like this `import * as methodName from '../../../app/main-app/main-app.component';`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! And one more question, is it possible to import it from a dynamic path(i.e app/main-app/main-app.component may change to app/main-abc/main-abc.component)

Comment: glad to know that worked for you. please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import * from '../../../app/main-app/main-app.component';
```

if you want to access their methods as well than you can use this

```
import * as methodName from '../../../app/main-app/main-app.component';
```

also i dont think you can Import dynamic class name from dynamic path bcoz there must be something static.

PS:- Posting this as answer may help someone another.